# Bootstrap check box not updating on Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, computed-properties

I'm trying to create a checkbox that selects all checkboxes.

I have an array of objects. Inside each object is a allowed value. Which states if a checkbox is active. The array is coming from a computed propertie which is getting the data from a getter in my store.

I have created a single checkbox and when it's selected it mutates my state. The state is getting updated, but my template isn't rendering the correct value.

I can see in my Vue console the state is being updated and in the console.log() in the computed properties.

I want the computed properties to display to correct data. I've tried moving everything to a method and calling the method, but it still isn't showing. When i'm understand of the Vue docs. Computed props should update if a value is updated.

How is it that my template isn't updating? and how can I update it?

template

```
<b-form-checkbox
   v-model="allSelected"
   :indeterminate="indeterminate"
   @change="toggleAll"
>Select All

</b-form-checkbox>
   <b-row>
    <b-col v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id" sm="12" md="6" lg="4">
      <b-form-checkbox
        
        :value="cat"
        v-model="cat.allowed"
      />
      <span>{{ cat.name }}</span>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>


  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("categories", ["customerCategories"]),

  categories() {
   return this.customerCategories;
  },
```

},

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("categories", ["updateToggle"]),

   toggleAll() {
    this.updateToggle(this.allSelected);
   },
  }
```

....store

```
  updateToggle({ commit }, data) {
    commit("isCategoriesActive", data);
  }

    isCategoriesActive: (state, value) =>
      (state.list = state.list.map(cat => {
      cat.allowed = value
    return cat
   })),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this solution, with `v-model` reference to a `computed` getter/setter: [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

The only thing from my example you need to change is:

1. Where the cats array is stored
2. getter/setter in the computed `allSelected`

```js
<script>
export default({
  data () {
    return {
      cats: [
        { name: "one", allowed: false},
        { name: "two", allowed: false},
        { name: "three", allowed: false},
        { name: "four", allowed: false},
        { name: "five", allowed: false}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    allSelected: {
      get () {
        return this.cats.every(cat => cat.allowed)
      },
      set (value) {
        this.cats.map(cat => cat.allowed = value)
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>
allSelected: <input type="checkbox" v-model="allSelected" />
  <hr />
  <template v-for="cat in cats" :key="JSON.stringify(cat)">
  <div>
    {{cat.name}} : <input type="checkbox" v-model="cat.allowed" />
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
```